# Firestore valueChanges() only emits once when using take(1)

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a document called `booking` in the `counts` collection (`counts/booking`) of my firestore database. I want to read data from this booking document and listen for value changes too. How can I achieve this using AngularFire2?

I have tried the following code,

```
this.afs.collection('counts').doc<Count>('booking').valueChanges().pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
          this.newCount = data.newCount;
          this.otherCount = data.otherCount;
        }
      });
```

This reads the value but doesn't seem to update the values as it changes in the firestore document.

Comment: why you're doing `.pipe(take(1))` ?

Comment: `take(1)` will effectively have it only execute a single (1) time. If you remove `take(1)` does it have the desired result?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes it works (: Thank you.

Comment: @AjaySivan I created an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `take(1)` pipeable operator as this will cause your code to effectively only execute/emit a single (1) time:

```
this.afs.collection('counts').doc<Count>('booking').valueChanges()
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      this.newCount = data.newCount;
      this.otherCount = data.otherCount;
    }
  });
```

Hopefully that helps!